# File downloading not working in node

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

I am using res.download() and the file is getting downloaded as well.But the pdf which is uploaded on the server and which I am getting with res.download is different i.e the one which I am getting downloaded is blank pdf.ALso a 200 response is returned in my server i.e that the file is present.
Below is my code:
Controller:

```
$http.get('/api/knowledges').success(function(data){
        console.log("this is your data");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.knowledge=data;
    });
    $scope.download=function(fileDownload){

      function downloadFile(filePath){
        console.log("download funcion invoked");
        console.log(filePath);
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href = filePath;
        //link.download = "my.pdf"
        link.click();
      }
      downloadFile('/api/knowledges/file_download/?filepath='+fileDownload.file_details.path);
    }
```

API:

```
exports.download = function(req, res) {
  var filename='BookWorm Study Material.pdf';
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  res.download(req.query.filepath,filename);
};
```

Comment: check if `req.query.filepath` is correct, you are getting empty pdf because, content type is set to pdf, check the `fillepath` by console

Comment: Everything is correct.I even removed the content type:pdf code but it is giving me a blank file whose size is 718kb whereas my original file of 14 pages is 389 KB.